# Domain analysis in surveys

Tags: survey

When using the survey procs in SAS on imputed dated, is it best to include the 
imputation variable on the table or domain statement, or should it be 
included on the by statement?  I found one paper 
(http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/265-2010.pdf) that 
included it on the domain statement which seems kind of strange to me 
since imputations are not really subsets of the data in the same way 
something like a grouping based on age or sex or race is.  Can someone 
explain?  Thx.

Comment: do you have a specific data set you're working with? - public use data technical documentation varies a _lot_ in the methods they recommend for multiple imputation.  here's some r code displaying the recommended methodology for PISA, PIAAC, SCF, SBO, NHIS, and the CE  ..it's rare that two are the same. https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/search?q=mitools&ref=cmdform

Comment: @Anthony Damico-NHIS.  Their documentation shows how to handle domain analysis for subgroups, but not imputations.  I'm not an R user, but it looks like the R code you reference is for aggregating imputed data sets, not domain analysis.  So, it's still unclear.

Comment: if you just want to parrot [the sas domain command](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveymeans_a0000000251.htm), then are you just looking for the `svyby` command at [line 504](https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/blob/master/National%20Health%20Interview%20Survey/2011%20personsx%20plus%20samadult%20with%20multiple%20imputation%20-%20analyze.R#L504)??